# How to parse Date properly in JS?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have tried to check the date string whether it is date type or not by using the following code in **JS**,

```
var dateString = "2015";
Date.parse(dateString)
```

But it always returns the parsed string as 1420070400000.

**In C#**

If i check the date string with **DateTime.TryParse** method, it gives **false** result as "2015" is not date.

```
DateTime.TryParse("2015", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the best way to check the date string whether it is date or not?

Comment: use moment.js. it has fantastic features and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Date.parse returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or NaN if not valid.

To retrieve a valid date object you must construct a new date object as well

```
new Date(Date.parse(2015))
```

You could of course extend the string or date prototype if you want it more c# style

```
String.prototype.TryParseToDate = function() {
    var parsedDate = Date.parse(this);
    // todo, implement errorhandling
    return new Date(parsedDate);
};

"2015".TryParseToDate(); // this returns the parsed date


Date.prototype.TryParse = function(inputString) {
    var parsedDate = Date.parse(inputString);
    // todo, implement errorhandling
    return new Date(parsedDate);
};

var date = new Date();
date.TryParse("2015"); // this returns the parsed date
```

Example with error handling

```
String.prototype.TryParseToDate = function() {
    var parsedDate = Date.parse(this);

    if(isNaN(parsedDate)){
        throw "Not a valid date";
    }

    return new Date(parsedDate);
};



try {
    "IWillCrash".TryParseToDate();
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

**Update**

As @orhor pointed out extending prototypes may be considered as an anti pattern, especially if you are building large systems. For the small ones I'd say nae, don't bother. If need be there are a couple of options, I typically build a util library or wrap everything in my own classes where the latter is my favorite since it scales pretty good when project grows.

Below is an example of a date util wrapper.

```js
var myDateUtils = function(){
 var that = this;

 that.TryParseToDate = function(value) {
     var parsedDate = Date.parse(value);

     if(isNaN(parsedDate)){
         throw "Not a valid date";
     }

     return new Date(parsedDate);
 };

 // place other functions here
 that.Greet = function(){
  console.log("Hello");
 }

 // return constructed object
 return that;
}


// construct object wrapper
var myDate = new myDateUtils();
myDate.Greet();

// Will crash
try {
 var result = myDate.TryParseToDate("IWillCrash");
    console.log(result);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

// Will succeed 
try {
 var result = myDate.TryParseToDate("2015");
    console.log(result);
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: but be aware of the fact that extending prototypes may not allways be recommended approach
https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gRYXV5KXKM60wAO_9aDIBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=why%20to%20avoid%20extending%20prototype

Comment: Agree to be careful, but in this case it's properly done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, but I'm not sure.

```
function isStringValidDate(ds)
{
var d=new Date(ds);
if(d && d.getFullYear()>0) 
return true;
else 
return false;
}
```